# Sencha Touch: How to determine when a class has been loaded

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch 2 app which uses [shepsii's sqlite proxy](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?195991). When the app loads, I see in the Chrome console several errors similar to this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getConnection' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/app/store/OptionsOfflineStore.js:14
```

This error occurs on each of my stores. The proxy on each store is defined as follows:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'sqlitestorage',
    dbConfig: {
        tablename: 'user',
        dbConn: Utils.InitSQLite.getConnection()
    }
}
```

and the line beginning 'dbConn' is the offending line. The app runs fine despite these errors in Chrome and when debugging from eclipse on an Android device. However, when I export a signed app package and install that on the device, it hangs at the loading screen. I can't see any other errors, so I'm assuming that it's these store-related errors which are preventing the app from loading.

I guess that the reason the error occurs is that the class defined in utils/InitSQLite is not fully loaded before the app goes ahead and attempts to run the store code, hence the InitSQLite class is 'undefined'.

Is there any way that I can detect in Sencha Touch when a class is fully loaded/an object is instantiated, so that I can delay loading the stores code until InitSQLite is ready?

Comment: This problem seems to have resolved itself. This is the second occasion when I've had an odd problem on an Android device using the SenchaTouch-Applaud-Eclipse combination, which has simply gone away of its own accord. It's a relief, of course, but kind of unsettling that I had no idea where it came from in the first place, and hence when it might return.

Answer (score 0):

define in store config `autoLoad:false` and don't set dbConn in proxy, then:

```
Ext.myInterval = setInterval(function(){
  try{
    if(Utils && Utils.InitSQLite && Utils.InitSQLite.getConnection){
      Ext.apply(store.getProxy(),{
        dbConn: Utils.InitSQLite.getConnection()
      });
      store.reload();
      clearInterval(Ext.myInterval);
    }
  catch(ex){}
},300);
```

Comment: That looks like it makes good sense. Thank you. I'll give it a go, though I think I will need to have the stores autoloading at later points in my app.